How I can convert a APK file to a WGT file
I want to convert it for my Samsung TV. Polaris is no longer. I found an app. Is Androzen but I don't find a link to this app for my computer.
Please help me
I searched a lot by internet to solve it. But I don't found nothing more tha that I said.

As far as I know, APK (Android Application Package, recently, AAP) can't be converted to WGT (Tizen Web App packaging). Recent Samsung TV is using Tizen Platform.
